# Iterate over unknown nested lists

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I need to iterate over unknown nested lists and size (subcategories.subcategories.subcategories etc..) and check if any values in my array contains the nested lists values. I might need an recursive function. How could i make this possible.

Here is my code so far (it will not check deeper then 2 level)

```
 for (int counter = 0; counter < filteredList[0].subcategories.Count; counter++)
 {
       var item = filteredList[0].subcategories[counter].questionanswer;

       for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
       {
           var results = Array.FindAll(questionIDs, s => s.Equals(item[i].id.ToString()));
           if (results.Length > 0)
           {
               QuestionViewModel question = new QuestionViewModel();
               question.formattedtext = item[i].formattedtext;
               question.id = item[i].id;
               question.sortorder = item[i].sortorder;
               question.breadCrum.AddRange(breadCrumCategoryId);
               filteredQuestions.Add(question);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's unknown nested lists? Can you post the structure of filtered list and subcategories?

Comment: Filtered list and subcategories includes 4 properties (header, id, parentcategoryid and sortorder) and 2 lists (subcategories and questionanswer)

Comment: @kalle don't explain your code. show it..

Answer (score 0):

Been writing recursive functions for 40 years.  If I can't recurse, nobody can.  Best way is define classes. Normally done like code below.  Add properties to class like Name, Rank, Serial Number.

```
 public class Category
    {
        List<Category> children { get; set; }
    }​
```